# font-face fonts not working when hosting online

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, typography

I am using font-face for fonts and when I upload it to testing server its not showing and also not showing any errors also so could not figure out the issue , could anyone help me in this  to figure out why is it not showing ?

> I have uploaded the fonts to root beside root html file

```
   <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Hanson';
        src: url('Hanson-Bold.ttf');
        src: url('Hanson-Bold.otf');
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'vag';
        src: url('VAGRoundedBT-Regular.otf');
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Vagbold';
        src: url('VAGRoundedStd-Bold.otf');
  
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Vaglight';
        src: url('VAGRoundedStd-Light.ttf');
        src: url('VAGRoundedStd-Light.otf');
  
      }
      body {
        font-family: 'vag';
      }
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code snippet and a link to the page where your are facing this issue? This snippet doesn't contain any cause for your issue.

Comment: @VishalBiswas https://codepen.io/feizel/pen/XWjvWqp

Answer (score 1):

**you maybe need to modify your .htaccess file, add this lines :** 
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
 AddType font/opentype otf
 AddType font/truetype ttf
 AddType application/x-font-woff woff
 Be sure also that the file is there  and the name is exactly the same (case sensitive)